# How to refresh only the combobox using LWC when new record is created?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, refreshapex

I want to put the created value as a default value in Combobox using LWC
So when i create new record i want it to be set a default value in Combobox

[image]

JS:

```
 @wire(retrieveFields)
    getUserListViews({data,error}) {
        
        if(data){
        var listViewArray = [];
        for(var listnameValue in data) {
            
            var listLabel = data[listnameValue].Name;
            this.listviewId = data[listnameValue].Id;
            var listviewObj = {label: listLabel, value: this.listviewId};
            listViewArray.push(listviewObj);
        }
        this.listViewsNames = listViewArray;
        this.listviewId = this.listViewsNames.value;
        }else {
            window.console.log(error);
        }
        
    }  


handleChange(event) {
    this.listviewId = event.detail.value;
}

openmodal() {
    this.openmodel = true
}
closeModal() {
    this.openmodel = false
} 
handleFieldChange(e) {
    if (e.currentTarget.fieldName === "Name") {
        this.name = e.target.value;
      } else if (e.target.name === "userId") {
        this.industry = e.target.value;        
      }
}
saveMethod() {
    this.handleIsLoading(true);
    const fields = {};

    fields[Name_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.name;
    fields[User_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.userId; 
    const recordInput = {
    apiName: LISTVIEW_OBJECT.objectApiName,
    fields: fields
    };
    createRecord(recordInput)
        .then(record => {
            
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'la liste view a été bien créee',
                    variant: 'success'
                })
            );
            this.listviewId = this.listViewsNames[0].value;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error creating record',
                    message: error.body.message,
                    variant: 'error'
                })
            );
        }).finally(()=>{
            this.handleIsLoading(false);
        }); 
        this.closeModal();
}

handleIsLoading(isLoading) {
    this.isLoading = isLoading;
}

updateRecordView() {
   setTimeout(() => {
        eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();");
   }, 1000); 
}
```

HTML :

```
lightning-layout-item size="12">
                    <lightning-combobox
                    name="fieldInfo"
                    label="REQUETE"
                    value={listviewId}
                    placeholder="Selectionner une liste view "
                    options={listViewsNames}
                    onchange={handleChange} >
                    </lightning-combobox>
        </lightning-layout-item>
```

Apex :

```
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
  public static List_View__c[] getUserListViews(){
    return [SELECT Id, Name FROM List_View__c WHERE User__c = :UserInfo.getUserId() ORDER BY Name ASC];
}
```

How to use  **RefreshApex** method to fetch new created values and display them in combobox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a wire going to an object rather than a method.
This means you need to use `getters` to provide your list view array, but this makes it very clean:

```
@wire(retrieveFields)
listViewResults;


get listViews(){
  if (!this.listViewResults.data){
    return [];
  }
  let tempListViews = [];
  for(var listnameValue in this.listViewResults.data) {
      let lv = data[listnameValue];
      tempListViews.push({label: lv.Name, value: lv.Id});
  }
  //not sure what this is... prob should be another getter and use the zero index?
  //this.listviewId = this.listViewsNames[].value;
  return tempListViews;
  
}

listViewId_
get listViewId(){
  return ((!this.ListViewId_) ? this.listViews[0]?.value : this.listViewId_);
}
```

`listViewId` also needs a setter, here:

```
set listViewId(v){
  listViewId_ = v;
}
```

Now you can call `refreshApex` because you now have access to the full
results object (`listViewResults`)

eg (best to put in your `finally` handler):

```
}).finally(()=>{
  this.refreshApex(this.listViewResults);
});
```

Comment: `this.listViewResults` will never be undefined/null. You instead need to check if `this.listViewResults.data != undefined`.

Comment: Thank you - good point. Amended.

Comment: it doesnt work , the combobox doesn't work anymore

Comment: At this point, you need to open up the console and start debugging. I think it's related to the listViewId which I suggested should be a getter. I'm going to make an amendment to my answer which should hopefully resolve this (you need to get and set it, and currently, I'm not handling that in the code)

Comment: Yes but no console are showing , i guess the method *get listViews(){* isn't called in initialization of the page , besides i guess i need the change the options values of the combobox  *options={listViewsNames}*

Comment: Yes try that... sorry I may have changed some names

Comment: Can we chat in private?

Comment: **this.listViewResults.data** is undefined ..

Comment: try this.listViewResults?.data

Comment: I'm blocked from posting new questions since 2 weeks ago , my questions seems clear and it respects the site's politics - should i wait for some more time?